# How do I make a RichFaces rich:panel behave like a link?

Tags: jsf, richfaces, hyperlink

I have a simple `rich:panel`. I would like it to behave like one big link to some page. Is that even possible? How?

For example: the [section about `rich:dataGrid`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html_single/#rich_dataGrid) in the RichFaces manual show a grid of car descriptions. Suppose I wanted to make each panel link to a detailed page for that car, how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example is based on RichFaces 3:

```
<rich:panel>
   <a4j:support event="onclick".../>
</rich:panel>
```

or this:

```
<a4j:outputPanel>
  <a4j:support event="onclick".../>
  <rich:panel></rich:panel>
</h:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Well, if you need to navigate to a different page than you don't even need to use a4j:support. Use onclick and navigate to a different page there.

Answer (score 1):

It should have an onclick event, you can attach Ajax support to the panel via that event.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. Could you post an example?

Comment: Something like this:  onclick='window.location.href = url'